# data:image location in ionic3 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, image-uploading

i am making image upload using ionic 3 app and FileReader , after the image is uploaded i get this as image url 
data:image/jpeg;base64,/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ...9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD/AD/6AP/Z 
something like this , then i store it as is into my database 
i noticed that if i open the app at another device the image will still be loaded and show in the view . so i wounder where does this image go after i upload it? where is it saved in my app ? i tried to look into my app folders couldn't find the img

thanks,

Comment: share the code you are using, its hard to help you without further context

Comment: i added the code below

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i am using

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ 'ITEM_CREATE_TITLE' | translate }}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button (click)="cancel()">
        <span color="primary" showWhen="ios">
          {{ 'CANCEL_BUTTON' | translate }}
        </span>
        <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="done()" [disabled]="!isReadyToSave" strong>
        <span color="primary" showWhen="ios">
          {{ 'DONE_BUTTON' | translate }}
        </span>
        <ion-icon name="md-checkmark" showWhen="core,android,windows"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Ts file:

```
export class ItemCreatePage {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;
  isReadyToSave: boolean;

  item: any;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      profilePic: [''],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      about: ['']
    });

    // Watch the form for changes, and
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
      this.isReadyToSave = this.form.valid;
    });
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

  getPicture() {

      this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();

  }
  processWebImage(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {

      let imageData = (readerEvent.target as any).result;
      this.form.patchValue({ 'profilePic': imageData });
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  getProfileImageStyle() {
    return 'url(' + this.form.controls['profilePic'].value + ')'
  }

  /**
   * The user cancelled, so we dismiss without sending data back.
   */
  cancel() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  /**
   * The user is done and wants to create the item, so return it
   * back to the presenter.
   */
  done() {
    if (!this.form.valid) { return; }
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Ahmad, you just shared some bits and pieces of code that is disconnected from your question. You should upload fully working example if you want help. At least you should have all the key files involved. This above is not helpful.

Comment: sorry my friend :( 

i made new ionic project using super app mode ,

it has a page for create item , you can upload image inside it . 

after i upload the image , it will be viewed inside my html as <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ...9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD/AD/6AP/Z ">

i just dont know where is the image stored inside my app . that's all i need to know . sorry for wasting your time :) and thx for trying to help

Comment: :) so dataUrl - IS the image actually. Your img element reads this "dataURI" and obtains details of how to render it from it. Sorry I was also a bit confused;) - so there is no file that you can access but there s base64 "string" basically that represents that image.

Comment: so if i upload that image and store the base64 string into my database , and for example i gave you the app and request that data url into an image , it will convert the base64 string to an image and display it for you right? it wont be uploaded into my app files and add extra size am i correct ?
and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes correct, if i will use your app that will get its img data from this dataurl you dont need a file or erc to show it